# Event Listeners not displaying in Chrome Devtools - Linux

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events

Are there any settings or things that might block the `event Listeners` from displaying correctly in `devtools`?

`Linux Mint 18.1 64-bit` Chrome version: `Version 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit)`

[image]

Comment: https://crbug.com/700876

Comment: The same here with the same version of chrome, but on Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is fixed with latest version. 59.X

Comment: Ah amazing! This was a bloody nightmare for me!